Why are there both "was" and "wozu" in this sentence: "Auf jeden Fall ist es mir vollkommen egal, was Sie denken, wozu Sie ein Recht hätten!"?
Auf jeden Fall ist es mir vollkommen egal, was Sie denken, wozu Sie ein Recht hätten! is a quote from a German-dubbed version of the movie A few good men (Eine Frage der Ehre). In the original the line is Either way, I don't give a damn what you think you're entitled to!.
What confuses me is the presence of both was (what) and wozu (to what) — which seems to be the same thing repeated twice?
As far as I can tell ... egal, wozu Sie ein Recht hätten! is grammatically correct. So why isn't ... egal, wozu Sie denken Sie ein Recht hätten!?
Is there a rule that deals with this specific situation — and which I could be directed to? I couldn't really formulate a proper search query to google.

Do you have the full German version of the sentence? It's hard to compare your version with the book's translation if you don't say what the book's translation is.

Es ist mir egal, wozu ... and Es ist mir egal, was Sie denken, wozu ... are both grammatically correct but convey different meanings.

I believe you have been tricked by English grammar here. In English, there is only one pronoun despite the presence of two verbs (to be entitled to and to think). In the German sentence, each of these gets its own object as a pronoun.

@RHa: No, the object of "denken" is already the next embedded clause, so it cannot additionally have "was" as its object.

@Alazon the object is present twice here, as a pronoun and as a subordinate clause. I don't know if this is a Korrelat in a strict sence, but it is at least similar.

As a German native speaker I read the German, thought 'what?', read the English, understood the meaning, reread the German, and then though 'yeah, it can mean the same as the English'. So the German is technically correct but definitely not easy or straightforward to parse.

@RHa: Scope-marking "was" cannot be a Korrelat that signals a following question, because the verb "denken" does not select a question (semantically).

Ich meine, es sollte auf Deutsch lauten: "Auf jeden Fall ist mir vollkommen egal, wozu Sie denken, ein Recht zu haben". Die dazu passende Begründung kann ich leider nicht liefern, nur meinem Sprachgefühl folgen und theoretisch dilettieren: Gelesen habe ich den dt. Satz beim ersten Mal, als würde dem Anderen mit dem letzten Teilsatz eingeräumt, dass er durchaus das Recht hat dies zu denken, mit Betonung auf dem ersten "Sie", nicht auf "denken".  "… egal, was Sie denken, wozu Sie ein Recht haben!" wäre auch ok. Dem anderen soll ja unterstellt werden, dass er das Recht zu etwas hat, nicht …

"… konditional, dass er diese Recht hätte (, wenn ...)". Er denkt, dass er das Recht dazu hat. Will man unterstreichen, dass man dem gerade nicht zustimmt, würde man sagen "dass er das Recht habe." Die Fachwörter, die diese Aussage unterfüttern sollten, fehlen mir allerdings, daher nur ein Kommentar.

The was and the wozu are parts of different subordinate clauses, so there is no repetition.
The first subordinate clause is was Sie denken and refers to egal.
Es ist mir egal, was Sie denken = I don't care what you think.
The second subordinate clause is wozu Sie ein Recht hätten and refers to denken.
Sie denken, wozu Sie ein Recht hätten = you think what you'd be entitled to.

Attention: This is wrong, as detailed in my answer. – It is true that, contentwise, there is an element of "I don't care what you think", but this doesn't get the grammar right.

maybe the last one is better translated "… what you think you have a right to do/have"

The name of the phenomenon is scope marking. This is a complicated issue because it is about forming questions in multiple embedded clauses...
So, "was" is not a real question word but it is a place-holder, a scope-marker. It is needed to mark the point at which the embedded question starts, although the real question word "wozu" cannot appear there. But the "wozu" is the core of what the question is about: "Er denkt, er hat ein Recht dazu"; "He thinks he is entitled to it" – to what? Whatever, I don't care. So the predicate "es ist mir egal" introduces variants and provokes the (indirect) question.
This doesn't change when the whole thing is additionally described from the other's point of view, embedding it under the verb "think": "He thinks he is entitled to something, but I don't care what it is." –  Note that what Tilman Schmidt writes above is not correct: "Ich denke, wozu ich ein Recht habe" is actually ungrammatical. Or if you manage to get it, it is the wrong question. The basic message is: "I don't care what..." and not "he thinks what...".
Now, let's get to building up the indirect question. The question has to follow the predicate I-don't-care: "I don't care (give a damn), what he thinks he is entitled to." What is different in German, however, is that you have to use a compound question word "to what = wozu", and additionally the verb "entitled to" corresponds to a construction with a noun. So you would get:

Es ist mir egal, wozu er denkt, dass er ein [Recht __] hat".

This is a structure that you might expect, and if it's acceptable it would show that the verb "denken" does not embed a question (because the paraphrase has "dass", indicating a declarative clause). So when you start analysing the example in terms of a question "was denkt er...", you are stuck and you cannot integrate the rest of the clause with the question word "wozu" into the structure.
DavidVogt has said in a comment that he finds the above example ok, but in my intuition it is not quite grammatical. Maybe it's a borderline case. In any case, it strains the grammar because you are moving a prepositional phrase (wozu = to what) and it depends on the noun "Recht", not as in English on the verb. So in German you have to dig too deep to find the place that the question word relates to, or to put it differently: the distance covered when you prepose the question word "wozu" to too long. (This is a classic topic in the theory of "wh-movement" and "subjacency" in Generative Grammar).
But the question word has to be preposed, because the phrase "I don't care" is what demands that the following clause should be an indirect question.
So the solution in German is to leave the question word "wozu" in a deeper clause and indicate the size of the question (Q) by a dummy "was". The structure can be developed in a stepwise fashion:

Es ist mir egal Q:[Sie denken, [Sie haben ein Recht wozu]]
Es ist mir egal Q: [Sie denken, [wozu Sie ein Recht haben]]
Es ist mir egal [was Sie denken, [wozu Sie ein Recht haben]]

So here, "Q:Sie denken Sie haben ein Recht wozu" means in a less grammatical and more logical notation: "I don't care about which x it is  such that you think that you are entitled to x"
By the way, this can also be extended: "Was meinst du, was sie glaubt, wen sie gesehen hat?" (question is about the x such that: Du meinst, dass sie glaubt, dass sie x gesehen hat") (example from Haider, see below).
*
Literature: Hubert Haider: The syntax of German, Cambridge UP 2010, Chapter 3.3: "Partial wh-movement".

I have no problem with es ist mir egal, wozu er denkt, dass er ein Recht hat. The prepositional phrase doesn't behave like a dependant of the noun in dazu hat er kein Recht or ein Recht hat er dazu aber nicht, either.

Maybe, strong focus accent on "wozu" might help to make the long movement sound more grammatical. – And yes, there are topicalisation options that don't respect an NP-node, cf. also: "Darüber ist [ein kleines Buch --] entstanden" (Dudengrammatik (2022), S. 64 f. / Randnr. 37 „Satzgliedteile im Vorfeld“). I don't think this refutes the bracketing I gave.

... and then, here it's long movement, unlike the simple topicalisation examples.
